# Absolute value of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, intuition

I have never encountered this concept before. Is this equation valid for $y>0$?

$$\mathbb{P}(|X|>y) = \mathbb{P}(-|X|<y<|X|)$$

What about this?

$$\mathbb{P}(|X|>y) = \mathbb{P}(X>y) + \mathbb{P}(X<-y)$$

Comment: No the first one ($y$ could be negative), yes to the second.

Comment: @MichaelBurr : $-|X| < y < |X|$ means $-|X| < y$ and $y < |X|$, so $|X| > -y$ and $|X| > y$

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman $y>0$ was already specified. Would the first statement be true then?

Comment: @ChristopherCarlHeckman My question was more rhetorical ...

Comment: @S.Tessa : (Blinks) Yes, I guess it was. ... As for the first equation, $y > -|X|$ if $y>0$, so it's trivially true.

Comment: @Bungo You're right, I didn't read the posting carefully.  As written, the statements in the first line are not strongly connected...

Comment: Your first identity is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> I have never encountered this concept before. Is this equation valid for $y>0$?
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(|X|>y) = \mathbb{P}(-|X|<y<|X|)$$

Yes, for all *strictly positive* $y$, then $-\lvert X\rvert < y <\lvert X\rvert$ is an equivalent event to $y<\lvert X\rvert $.

However, whether this is helpful is another matter.   Does it simplify anything?

> What about this?
>
> $$\mathbb{P}(|X|>y) = \mathbb{P}(X>y) + \mathbb{P}(X<-y)$$

Yes the event that $\lvert X\rvert > y$ is equivalent to the union of the events that $X>y$ or $-X>y$, and because *for strinctly positive* $y$, these are disjoint events, then $$\mathbb{P}(|X|>y) ~=~ \mathbb{P}(X>y) + \mathbb{P}(-X>y)$$

This may be much more helpful.

---

Note: the requirement that $y>0$ is necessary.   Neither holds otherwise.